# plot_model, evaluate_model (pycaret) not producing any output in Azure databricks

Tags: python, azure, azure-databricks, pycaret

Im trying to evaluate / plot the various model results using `pycaret` but I'm not able to do so.
for example :-

```
from pycaret.datasets import get_data
juice = get_data('juice')
from pycaret.classification import *
exp_name = setup(data = juice,  target = 'Purchase',silent=True,html=False)
lr = create_model('lr')
evaluate_model(lr)
```

produces this output on console :-

`interactive(children=(ToggleButtons(description='Plot Type:', icons=('',), options=(('Hyperparameters', 'parameter'), ('AUC', 'auc'), ('Confusion Matrix', 'confusion_matrix'), ('Threshold', 'threshold'), ('Precision Recall', 'pr'), ('Prediction Error', 'error'), ('Class Report', 'class_report'), ('Feature Selection', 'rfe'), ('Learning Curve', 'learning'), ('Manifold Learning', 'manifold'), ('Calibration Curve', 'calibration'), ('Validation Curve', 'vc'), ('Dimensions', 'dimension'), ('Feature Importance', 'feature'), ('Feature Importance (All)', 'feature_all'), ('Decision Boundary', 'boundary'), ('Lift Chart', 'lift'), ('Gain Chart', 'gain'), ('Decision Tree', 'tree'), ('KS Statistic Plot', 'ks')), value='parameter'), Output()), _dom_classes=('widget-interact',))`

instead of the beautiful widgets and graphs it is supposed to display.

Also many parameters of `plot_model` wont work :-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the `evaluate_model()` function which displays a user interface for all of the available plots for a given model. internally uses the `plot_model()` function.

[image: REF1]
[image: Ref2]

It displays only one graph at a time when we pass graph name as an argument. And also, using `help(plot_model)` will provide you with different ways of graph representation.

[image: Ref3]

Comment: sorrry I didnt get you, I have sent you an examle, im not able to to graphs in `azure databricks`

Comment: hi, use plot_model(lr) you will get graphs

Comment: this is plotting the same as shown, but Im not getting the widgets and buttons,.on the other hand whrn I try to plot_model for another scenario ```fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(3,2,1)
plot_model(blender, plot='residuals', save=True, verbose=False, scale=1.1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(3,2,2)
plot_model(blender, plot='error', save=True, verbose=False, scale=1.1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(3,2,3)
plot_model(blender, plot='learning', save=True, verbose=False, scale=1.1)
plt.show()``` im not geting any plot

Comment: the code which you provided in the question and the comment differs, i am unable to understand what your ask. please edit question and provide more details for troubleshoot .

Comment: yes my concern is would  not `evaluate_model(model_name)` work on databricks? there are a lot of additinal graphs which evaluate_model shows

Comment: refrence : `https://www.databricks.com/session_na21/machine-learning-with-pycaret`

Comment: what is the differnce between usng `evaluate_model(model_name)` and  using 
 ID with plot `plot_model(lr,plot='feature_all')` . This is something I cannot understand

Comment: `evaluate_model` is not working in azure databricks. According to this [link](https://www.pycaret.org/tutorials/html/CLF101.html#10.4-Confusion-Matrix).evaluate_model internally uses `plot_model`.